# Unit testing IndexModel OnGet method with mocked User.Identity.Name

Tags: unit-testing

I am new to Testing and trying to unit test the function onGet()

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
     private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;
       
     public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
    {
     _logger = logger;
    }
       
     public IActionResult OnGet()
     {            
     var loggedInUser = User.Identity?.Name;
     /*sets the cookie and redirects*/
     }
    }
```

Below is my unit test:

```
public void OnGet_Test()
    {
      var mock = new Mock<ILogger<IndexModel>>();
      ILogger<IndexModel> logger = mock.Object;

      var test = new IndexModel(logger);
      IActionResult result = test.OnGet();
      Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result,typeof(RedirectToPageResult));

     }
```

This gives null reference exception as there is not value of User.Identity?.Name

I have tried many things including to mock it

```
var user_mock = new Mock<ControllerContext>();            
   user_mock.SetupGet(p => p.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name).Returns(“Test User”);
```

but how to set it up in the current context of the Test? as it keeps giving errors
error -Property or indexer 'PageModel.User' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
error - Property or indexer 'PageModel.HttpContext' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

If I mock HttpContext then also it’s the same problem how to set to in my class object?